# How to pin Redux Dev Tools Extension window to the Chrome browser

Tags: redux-devtools-extension

How to pin Redux Dev Tools Extension window to the bottom of the browser? If I click on the icon, it doesn't anchor to the bottom, it just floats.

I just figured out the answer, and I am posting as a q&a if anyone is having the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hit Ctrl+Shift+I, or F12.

You will then open up the Developer Tools.

Scroll to the right, and you will see a Redux tab at the end of Developer Tools.

[image]

Then select the bottom option to pin to the bottom:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to force Redux tab to appear in Chrome devtools? I have the Redux extension, however, that tab isn't there. I can only use Redux devtools by clicking on the extension icon near the address bar.

Comment: What worked for me was enabling chrome://flags/#enable-panels

Answer (score 9):

I faced similar issue. **I didn't have Redux tab in Chrome Dev Tools Panel after installing Redux DevTools**. Everything worked once I quitted the browser and reloaded it.